# npm install <package.name>

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

[I have to add package.json ,cors, body-parser in that directory. I tried to install them but they are not installing / appearing in my directed folder, please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk36U.png)

Answer (score 0):

The directory you're trying to install in does not contain a `package.json` file. This means that the directory is not an NPM project. To start it, run `npm init` and answer the questions the program asks you. Afterwards, your install command should work just fine.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH